# Using the IF function in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, if-statement, ms-office

I enter data for work to track call center times in the form of 0:00:05 or 0:01:30. I need to make a spreadsheet with a chart along with it narrowing down the data into columns for 0-4 seconds, 5-9 seconds, 10-14 seconds & >15 seconds. My supervisor advised me to use the IF function, but I can't seem to get a handle on it. Please help?

So far I have tried `=IF(cell<0:00:04,1,0)` but it comes up up with an error.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java or sql server?

Comment: =IF(cell<0:00:04,1,0), but it comes up up with an error @StormeHawke

Comment: Edit your question with more details instead of describing them in the comments

Comment: @pnuts I have the times in diffrent cells. I think that's one of the reasons for the error messages. I completed the spreadsheet and I tried your funtion, it works as long as I use it for one cell. When I attempt to use multiple cells it says that I have too many arguments.

Comment: @pnuts You totally lost me. Lol! But I did use the SUM function for each individual cell to get the totals, and then used your formula above to get a total number, but I need to break it down into seperated columns on 0-4 seconds, 5-9 seconds, 10-14 seconds, and <15 seconds (my supervisor said >15 which would be the same as 10-14 seconds, right?)

Comment: The info I need is "how long are abandoned calls" in Q I guess. Basically she wants to be able to tell whether or not they are kept on hold too long or if the calls just hang up because they dialed the wrong extension. Tha's why she wants it broken down into different columns of multiple increments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a data setup similar to this:

[image]

In cell F2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IF(D3="",COUNTIF(B:B,">="&TIME(,,D2)),COUNTIFS(B:$B,">="&TIME(,,D2),B:B,"<"&TIME(,,D3)))
```

You could then create a chart from the data in columns D:F.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you @tigeravatar & pnuts for the help. I'm not able to follow your advice (mentally). I don't want to keep asking the same questions and having you try to explain over and over. Sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: your answer was extremely close to my spreadsheet though. Thanks again.